# vbscript and checking for null

Tags: vbscript

On the line "If (IsNull(value)) then" below is my code correct? I want to check if the registry key exists and if not then show a web page.

```
Option Explicit
On error resume next
Dim SysVarReg, Value
Set SysVarReg = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
value = SysVarReg.RegRead ("HKCU\Software\test\FirstLogonComplete")

If (IsNull(value)) then

    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
    WshShell.Run "c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe https://intranet/start.htm"

    Dim SysVarReg2, Value2
    Value2 = "TRUE"
    Set SysVarReg2 = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    SysVarReg2.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\test\FirstLogonComplete", Value2

else
    wscript.echo "Already logged on"
end if
```

Answer (score 8):

In VBScript—where all variables are variants—variables can be one of two special values: EMPTY or NULL. EMPTY is defined as a variable with an un-initialized value, whereas NULL is a variable that contains no valid data.

If you want to test whether the variable namely 'value' is NULL or EMPTY then use following if statement:

```
If IsNull(value)  Or  IsEmpty(value) Then
   '...do something
End If
```

Answer (score 6):

If RegRead throws an error, then `value` is not initialized; an uninitialized variable has the value `Empty`, not `Null`.
Therefore, you should add the line

```
value = Null
```

after the `Dim` statement. Otherwise, `IsNull` would always return `False`.

Comment: The key here (no pun intended) is that RegRead [throws an error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x05fawxd%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) if the key doesn't exist, and the OP has `On Error Resume Next` turned on. Alternatively, one could use `IsEmpty(value)` instead of `IsNull(value)`.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean 'Null' or 'Nothing'?

In VBScript, Nothing means absence of value (or a null pointer).
Null is used to represent NULL values from a database.

See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f8tbc79x%28VS.85%29.aspx) for more info.

Also, see [this example](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/microsoft.public.windows.server.scripting/msg/33b8f015b189a00d?dmode=source) for how to detect if a registry key exists:

```
Const HKLM = &H80000002
Set oReg =GetObject("Winmgmts:root\default:StdRegProv")

sKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion"
If RegValueExists(HKLM, sKeyPath, sValue) Then
  WScript.Echo "Value exists"
Else
  WScript.Echo "Value does not exist"
End If

Function RegValueExists(sHive, sRegKey, sRegValue)
  Dim aValueNames, aValueTypes
  RegValueExists = False
  If oReg.EnumValues(sHive, sKeyPath, aValueNames, aValueTypes) = 0 Then
    If IsArray(aValueNames) Then
      For i = 0 To UBound(aValueNames)
        If LCase(aValueNames(i)) = LCase(sRegValue) Then
          RegValueExists = True
        End If
      Next
    End If
  End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to a business problem.  They wanted to make USB read-only so data couldn't wander off on thumb drives.  After pinging and connecting to WMI I had to determine whether or not the key already existed and the value was set.  On a couple thousand computers.

```
keyExists = fnReadKeyValue()

'======================================
'======================================


Function fnReadKeyValue()
    '   ' EXAMPLE VALUES
    '   const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
    '   strComputer = "."
    '   strKeyPath = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies"
    '   strEntryName = "WriteProtect"

    Set objReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
        strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

    objReg.GetDWordValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strEntryName, strValue
    if IsNull(strValue) then
        objLogFile.WriteLine "That registry value doesn't exist."
        fnReadKeyValue = "FAIL"
    else
        fnReadKeyValue = strValue
    end if

End Function
```